# Darboux Theorem for open interval

Tags: real-analysis

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29

In order for function to have the  intermediate value property , according to Darboux Theorem, can we use open interval like $(a,b)$  or we must closed interval like $[a,b]$ ?

because in some books it's written differently than Wiki. (closed interval)

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think $f(x)$ has to be differentiable on $(a,b)$ and *continuous* on $[a,b]$ (or equivalently the value $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ exist.) Differentiability at $a$ and $b$ cannot be defined in a simple manner.

On the other hand, if one requires differentiability on $(a,b)$ only, then $f(x)$ can be differentiable at every $x > a$, but $f(a)$ is not defined. For example $f'(x) \sim 1/x$ for $a=0$.